# How to create table view inside the cell using storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have created on nib file. In nib file i have one table view cell, In a cell i want to create a table view. But i am facing the problem to create a table view inside the cell. Please give me any suggestion on that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the table view into the prototype cell's contentView.  You'll probably want to make a UITableViewCell subclass in order to make it easier to encapsulate the datasource/delegate methods for the sub-tableview.

Answer (score 0):

It is too difficult solution.
Why can't you implement different cells in one table view?
Not use table in cell in table, just use one table with different cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tableviewceell control in nib/xib and than you can add table view in that cell.

I have tried once.

Hope you will get your answer.

:)